# gRPC error: "address not available" on Docker with NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, nestjs, grpc

I'm getting this error when starting my NestJS application on Docker with gRPC:

```
    {
        "created": "@1616799250.993753300",
        "description": "Only 1 addresses added out of total 2 resolved",
        "file": "../deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/chttp2_server.cc",
        "file_line": 403,
        "referenced_errors": [{
            "created": "@1616799250.993738500",
            "description": "Failed to add port to server",
            "file": "../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_custom.cc",
            "file_line": 403,
            "referenced_errors": [{
                "created": "@1616799250.993724200",
                "description": "Failed to bind to port",
                "file": "../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_uv.cc",
                "file_line": 72,
                "grpc_status": 14,
                "os_error": "address not available"
            }]
        }]
    }
```

The error does not occur on my local machine. Only on Docker.

Some useful info:

- My bootstrap URL: `localhost:5000`
- Docker image: `node:14-alpine`
- OS: macOS 11.2 Bug Sur
- Dockerfile:

```
    FROM node:14-alpine
    
    WORKDIR /app
    
    RUN apk -U --no-cache add protobuf \
      protobuf-dev \
      git \
      gcc \
      g++ \
      make \
      python
    
    COPY . .
    
    RUN git clone https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis.git /googleapis
    
    RUN npm install -g @nestjs/cli
    
    RUN npm install && sh compile.proto.sh
    
    RUN npm rebuild grpc --force
    
    CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

- docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: "3.7"
    
    services:
      health:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Docker/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - 5000:5000
-
```

- `protoc` script:

```
    protoc \
      --include_imports \
      --include_source_info \
      --proto_path=/googleapis \
      --proto_path=/googleapis/google/api \
      --proto_path=. \
      --descriptor_set_out=api_descriptor.pb \
      --plugin=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts_proto \
      --ts_proto_out=./src/health src/health/health.proto \
      --ts_proto_opt=outputEncodeMethods=false,outputJsonMethods=false,outputClientImpl=false
```

- protobuf for this example:

```
    syntax = "proto3";
    
    package health;
    
    service HealthService {
        rpc GetStatus(GetStatusRequest) returns (Status);
    }
    
    message Status {
        bool alive = 1;
    }
    
    message GetStatusRequest {}
```

- Application bootstrap:

```
    const logger = new Logger('Main');
    const url = 'localhost:5000';
    
    async function bootstrap() {
      const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
        AppModule,
        {
          transport: Transport.GRPC,
          options: {
            package: 'health',
            protoPath: join(__dirname, 'health/health.proto'),
          },
        },
      );
      await app.listen(() =>
        logger.log('Nest Service Template Listening on ' + url),
      );
    }
    bootstrap();
```

- `nest start`/`npm start` script output:
  [image: nest start]

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this error?

Comment: Can you provide more info! How do you launch your container?

Comment: Could you verify if the port you're trying to use is not already used by another process? You can use `lsof -i:3000` command to check if the port 3000 is used by some process. If so, kill it and retry.

Comment: @ErangaHeshan thanks! The port is not being used by some other process.

Comment: @zigarn okay, done!

Comment: Aren't multiple processes (or threads) inside your containers trying to expose port 5000?

Comment: @zigarn I don't see how it would be possible. I've added the application bootstrap to the post.

Comment: what does npm start perform?

Comment: @LucasResende I've added the npm start output to the post, does it answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

I've found the error (pretty dumb, by the way). I had to add the `url` parameter to the `grpcClientOptions` with `0.0.0.0:5000` (as the container does not recognize `localhost` without an alias).

This led me to another error: the gRPC package used by NestJS is built to the host machine when `npm install` is executed (in my case, to macOS), so it does not work inside the Linux container.

A possible solution is copying the whole project to the container and executing `npm install` inside the container -- which I think is not the best way to use Docker for local development.

Another one would be

```sh
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ npm install --target=12.0.0 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64 --target_libc=musl
```

Then you will not be able to run `npm start` locally, but it should work inside the container.

This issue will probably be fixed in the next major release of NestJS, since there is a pull request updating the gRPC package: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/6349.